# mobx-react create observable store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, mobx

I've been playing around with this for a while and am not sure if it's not possible or if I'm just missing something fundamental in ES6,React or MobX.

I want to have a mobx store in a separate file like below;

```
import { observable, action } from 'mobx';

export default class Store {

@observable data = [];

@action getAll(){
  this.data = [{
    itemTitle: 'Item One'
  },{
    itemTitle: 'Item Two'
  }]
  return this.data
}

@action pushItem(item){
  this.data.push(item)
}

addAfter5Secs(){
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('Item Added')
    this.pushItem({
    itemTitle: 'Item Two'
  })}, 5000)
}

constructor() {
  console.log('Store Created')
  this.getAll();
  this.addAfter5Secs()
}
}
```

Then I want to import it in a view AND create an instance of that store at that time.

```
import React from "react";
import { List, Button } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import { observer, inject } from 'mobx-react';
import Store from '../Data/Store';
import DevTools from 'mobx-react-devtools';

const dataItems = new Store

@observer
export default class ScriptsHome extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const items = observer(dataItems)
    return (
        <List>
        {items.data.map((reg, key) => {
          return(
            <List.Item key={key}>
                     <Button content={reg.itemTitle}/>
                </List.Item>)
          })}
          <DevTools />
        </List>
    );
  }
}
```

I do not want to pass it through a provider from the root component or have the store instantiated with the 'new' keyword in the export. I actually have dozens of stores so I only want them to be created as needed by views.

The above code will render the first 2 items, the 3rd item will be added to the store only after 5 seconds but the render is not fired on the component automatically so the item doesn't appear. When I force the render function to fire it will appear.

I am using a router to call this view so maybe that's also problematic?

I'm just learning Mobx, react, etc so any help is appreciated. All examples seem to use just one or two stores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after spending a bit of time with this it's turns out that it's not an issue at all with MobX. 
The versions of react and react router seemed to be the problem.
Using react router dom now and it's fine.